# SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION and the search path

Tags: sql, postgresql, session, postgresql-9.1

**The scenario**

```
CREATE SCHEMA testschema;
CREATE ROLE testrole LOGIN;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA testschema TO testrole;
ALTER ROLE testrole SET search_path = testschema;
```

Now if I initiate the connection (log in) as `testrole` then:

```
SHOW search_path;
```

Gives the desired result:

```
search_path 
-------------
testschema
(1 row)
```

However, if I initiate connection (log in) as a superuser and do:

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION testrole;
SHOW search_path;
```

Results in:

```
search_path   
----------------
"$user",public
(1 row)
```

(or whatever the search path of the superuser is)

---

My question is, why does `SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION` not affect the current `search_path`?
Is it a bug, by design or am I simply doinitwrong?

From the little I've found, the workaround of `SET SEARCH path = schemaname` after `SET SESSION...` seems to be the only solution, but that kind of defeats the purpose of having persistent search paths assigned to roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. I quote the manual on [`ALTER ROLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-alterrole.html)

> This only happens at login time; executing SET ROLE or SET SESSION
>   AUTHORIZATION does not cause new configuration values to be set.